# How to prevent Excel from display a formula's result until another cell is populated?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sorry I'm new to Excel but learning at a slow speed.

Why does `=IF(E3>=1,G3,NOW()-D3)` keep showing `41944`? Can i make it show nothing until a date is put into cell `D3`, or show `0`?

The formula's purpose is to return the number of days between the value in `D3` and today's date.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Looks like you got the problem answered.  You can accept an answer at any rep.  That will flag it as solved (and the person who posted the answer will receive more points than an upvote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `=IF(E3>=1,G3,if(isnumber(d3),NOW()-D3,0))`

Comment: I love the net and now you too :D Thanks, ill give you an up as soon as my rep goes up

Comment: @James - If you want the cell blank instead of 0, you can use empty double quotes.  You can also use ISBLANK() to test whether D3 is empty.  So a variation of LDC3's answer would be =IF(E3>=1,G3,if(isblank(D3),"",NOW()-D3))

Comment: Thank you that also works ill give them both a try see which is better to the eye

Answer (score -1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241072
Format the cell as Date. It is currently showing the serial number for the date instead of the date itself. In my experience this often happens when you're in number format instead of date

Comment: saw both answer, but it has to be a number as it shows the number of days the car has be on hire for not a date, what i did works, but i see 41944 until a date is put into, cell D3. i want it to show Blank. but i have tested all the formats